# Azure Table Storage RetryPolicy questions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

A couple questions on using RetryPolicy with Table Storage,

1. Is it best practice to use RetryPolicy whenever you can, hence use ctx.SaveChangeWithRetries() instead of ctx.SaveChanges() accordingly whenever you can?
2. When you do use RetryPolicy, for example,

   ctx.RetryPolicy = RetryPolicies.Retry(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

What values do people normally use for the retryCount and the TimeSpan?  I see 5 retries and 1 second TimeSpan are a popular choice, but would 5 retries 1 second each be too long?

Thank you,

Ray.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is highly dependent on your application and requirements.  The timeout errors to ATS happen so rarely that if a retry policy will not hurt to have in place and would be rarely utilized anyway.  But if something fishy is happening, it may save yourself from having to debug weird errors.

Now, I would suggest that in the beginning you do not enable the RetryPolicy at all and have tracing instead so that you can see any issues with persistence to ATS.  Once you're stabilized, putting a RetryPolicy maybe good idea to work around some runtime glitches on the ATS side.  Just make sure you're not masking your own problems with RetryPolicy.

Answer (score 1):

If your client is user facing like a web page you would probably like to use a linear retry with short waits (milliseconds) in between each retry, if your client is actually a non user facing backend service etc. then you would most likely want to use Exponential retries in order not to overload the table storage service in case it is already giving 5xx errors due to high load for instance.

Using the latest Azure Storage client SDK, if you do not define any retry policy in your table requests via the TableRequestOptions, then the default retry policy is used which is the Exponential retry. The sdk makes 3 retries in total for the errors that it deems retriable and this in total takes more or less 20 seconds if all retries fail.